# Long integer shape of Numpy arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

If I construct a numpy matrix like this:

```
A = array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]])
```

and then type `A.shape` I get the result:

```
(2L, 3L)
```

Why am I getting a shape with the format long?

I can restart everything and I still have the same problem. And as far as I can see, it is only when I construct arrays I have this problem, otherwise I get short (regular) integers.

Comment: `np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]).shape` gives me `(2, 3)`

Comment: What is the problem with long ? since [PEP237](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0237/) long and int are unified :).

Comment: What versions of python and numpy?

Comment: Are you perhaps running an old-ish version of python/numpy? The one I used in my answer are `2.7.2` (python) and `1.5.1` (numpy).

Comment: I have Python 2.7.1 and numpy 1.5.1, so that shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: I guess I can use long instead of short, but it seems unnecessary. But most of all, its really annoying...  :)

Comment: It could be an issue with 64 bit Linux where I32LP64 data model may be prevalent.  What is your OS?

Comment: @Abhijit I am using Windows 7, 64-bit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @CédricJulien puts it on the comment, there is no problem with long numbers in this case - this should be treated as an implementation detail.

The real answer for your question can, of course, only be found inside numpy's source code, but the fact that the dimensions are long in this case should not matter for any use you have for the arrays or these indexes.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, and I totally agree that as for performance of the code, it won't matter. However, there is the aesthetic point of view, and also my curiosity of course...  :)  But sure, the answer is inside numpy's source code.. Though, the question still remains, why does this happen to me, and no one else?  :)

Comment: As on why it happsn only to you, it should have to do to the way your NumPy is compiled. See @Abhijit's comment on the question.

Comment: It all depends where you got your Numpy. I had a version which did this not too long ago, a non-official 64-bit version.

Comment: It is happening on my workstation, at work (a highly respectable organization), so there shouldn't be any issues with my Windows 7 64-bit. But perhaps there is something with the way my Numpy is compiled. Though, I wouldn't know where to begin looking for errors. Especially since I don't have administrative access to my computer, and I can't uninstall and install programs...